# Is it good practice to clear the cache files generated by AdMob in Android?

Tags: android, caching, admob, android-webview

I have integrated AdMob in my Android app. I noticed the app taking up more and more storage space in a folder called app_webview generated by AdMob inside the app data folder. Should I clear the contents of this folder on each app exit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I clear the contents of this folder on each app exit ?

Why would you want to do that? Admob does this to provide better and speedy ad serving. And I'm sure the amount it is caching is within tolerable limits. Clearing that much space on the user's storage will not make him much happy. But you'll lose on revenue because of Admob trying to re-download all the stuff again. **It will lower your fill rate and thereby your revenue.**

There is no harm in doing it but you'll lose more (revenue) than you gain (user satisfaction). The user might not even notice it.

Comment: completely disagree with your answer... if you are developing a very simple app it is not reasonable that your app takes 5MB while admob stuff takes 50MB, it is even worse if your app targets low end devices...

Answer (score 0):

Admob is just caching its ads so they load quicker. The Android OS will clear the /cache directory if the filesystem gets too full, and Admob should be managing its own cache size. You shouldn't have to worry about it.

Comment: But users would tend to uninstall an app when they see it taking up too much storage I believe. The total size of my app is only around 10mb but this cache alone is taking up more than 20mb, so I was naturally concerned, any reason why I should not clear it besides the slower ad-loading time ?