# Why does my Unity ios app's Documents and Data keep increasing?

Tags: ios, caching, unity-game-engine, filesize, documents

I created my first app back in July. It came out to be 55mb. I have recently noticed that the Documents and Data section for my app is 150mb, nearly 3 times the app size. Doing more tests I have realized that each time I play the game it increases by 1mb. It is now at 170mb.
I am using Unity 5.6.1p4 and Google Admob. 
My app does not download any update files to run the game so that isn't the issue.
I have a couple of guesses but none seem very likely:
1) My game is only about half as optimized as it should be. I still use a lot of instantiate and destroy. An other post said that the memory issue is due to Apple's inability to garbage collect. That is a possibility but I cannot understand why the data from instantiate/destroy would be cached. I also find it hard to believe no one else has had that issue.
2) When the game first starts, it automatically loads a banner ad and a video ad so that there is no delay when the user first requests a reward video. Some people have said that Google Admob caches ads so there is less data usage. That seems like it would cause some increase in file size but 170mb is too much data to be cached. Again I find it hard to believe no one would have complained to Google about this before. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I cannot figure out what would be causing it. If you are interested in seeing the problem first hand, the App Store link is https://appsto.re/us/nco9gb.i

Comment: Have you ever tried to do some test with a version of the game without AdMob? Seems like you are not the first person with this "issue" https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/57669-iads-and-admob-increasing-app-size/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566994/is-it-good-practice-to-clear-the-cache-files-generated-by-admob-in-android https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/issues/237

Comment: Thank you very much. I have not tried that yet and will do so in the future. Thank you for the links to the other issues as well.

Comment: You are welcome,, it would be cool if you can make those experiments and add more info to your question or if it solves your problem post an answer :)

Comment: @mayo I removed anything relating to my app's ad system. I tested it 15 times exactly like I did before and now cannot get the Data above 1.4mb. So the issue is with Google Admob. 

I read that Admob should manage its own cache but if it is, its cap is way too high. A 55mb app should not be allowed to store 3 times its size in cached ads.

Does anyone know how I can change did or contact Google about his?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my findings: This is either an issue for older phones, or iOS 10.x.

 However, I do not know which. I am able to test iOS 10 on older phones (5, 5s and ipad 1). I am not able to find any newer device still running iOS 10. 
 This memory glitch does not seem to happen on iOS 11. I was able to test it on 3x iphone 6s, 2x iphone 7 all running iOS 11.
It is not as clear as I would like it to be but iOS 11 does not appear to have the memory issue. As much as I would like to find the cause and fix it, I think the majority of people should be safe because they update.